# How to replace single quote to two single quotes, but do nothing if two single quotes are next to each other in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I need to change all the single quote found in the string to two single quotes, if more than one single quotes are found successively, they should remain as it is.

e.g. str = abc'def''sdf'''asdf
output should be : str = abc''def''sdf'''asdf

Comment: what have you tried so far and in which language you want to achieve this

Comment: @Redo, i have tried /\'/\'\'/, but it changed the 2 single quotes to 4. Also tried /[^\']\'[^\']/, but it was replacing an extra character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cleanest way is to search for the following pattern:

```
(?<!')'(?!')
```

and then replace that with two single quotes.  The pattern searches for a single quote, but it has negative lookbehind and lookahead assertions which check that the preceeding and proceeding character is not also another single quote.

```
my $var = "abc'def''sdf'";
print "$var\n";
$var =~ s/(?<!')'(?!')/''/g;
print "$var\n";
```

Note that you could have also just written a straight pattern to match, e.g.

```
(^|[^'])'($|[^'])
```

But then the replacement becomes tricky because you would have consumed the characters surrounding the single quote.  I don't like to do extra work if I don't have to.

**Output:**

```
abc'def''sdf'
abc''def''sdf''
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester