# Match between two single quotes and continue matching if two single quotes appear in a row or if '.' appears in the middle?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pattern-matching

I'm trying to setup a regex pattern match that will match `'hello'` twice in `'hello'blah blah blah 'hello'` but that will match the full string `'hello''hello'` and the full string `'hello''hello'` as well as the full string `'hello'.'hello'`.

To put it simply, I want to start a match when there is a single quote, and continue the match until I encounter another single quote, unless there is another single quote immediately after it or if there is a `.'` after it, in which case I want to continue matching until I encounter a single quote that doesn't match those conditions.

This is what I have to match values between single quotes currently:

`\'[^\']*\'`

I already read the solution here: [How to replace single quote to two single quotes, but do nothing if two single quotes are next to each other in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45749597/how-to-replace-single-quote-to-two-single-quotes-but-do-nothing-if-two-single-q) but it doesn't quite fit what I'm looking for and can't get it to match the in-between stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
('[^']+'(?:\.?'[^']+')*)
```

It looks for a set of characters enclosed in single quotes, followed optionally by some number of sets of characters enclosed in single quotes, possibly preceded by a period.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PwYWHg/2)

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly! I wasn't aware you could continue matches by adding a non-capturing group with the stipulations like that.

Comment: @Cdhippen using the non-capturing group means that you just get the one match for the whole term rather than a set of sub-matches. btw I've modified the answer so that it will work if there are non-alphabetic characters between the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
'.*?'(\.?'.*?')*
```

If I understand your need correctly, it's easy to construct the above regex.

Comment: Unfortunately this creates differing groups vs full matches which messes with what I'm doing a bit too much. Nicks answer above does what I was looking for